# It was broken. Don't go there

Tags: grammar, verbs

There is a bridge on the drainage in bad condition.

My child and I walk by.

He wanted to cross the bridge.

"No, **it was broken**. Don't go there."

What is the exact word to used to describe to condition of the bridge?

[image]

Comment: I would say "It is dangerous." or "It is falling apart". *broken* usually isn't used to describe the condition of complex structures.

Comment: "Broken" works too, especially since the bridge you show is a very simple one, but you would have to say "it *is* broken", because that's its *current* condition.  *was* would mean that it was broken at some time in the past but isn't broken anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bridge, often we just say "[the bridge is out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbW47lgC95I)."  The more technical phrase, among architects and civil engineers, is that "the bridge has failed."

Of course, both of those expressions refer to more formal and permanent structures.  In the case of a bit of debris thrown over a ditch, as in your illustration, I would say that it's "dilapidated" and "unsafe".

Answer (score 2):

You can say, **"The bridge is damaged"** or **"The bridge is failing"**.

if you want to ask someone to keep away from a dangerous bridge you can say, **"The bridge isn't safe"** or **"The bridge is dangerous"**.